# Outlook add-in for an O365 group calendar

Tags: outlook, office365, outlook-web-addins

I have created an O365 group which comes with a default calendar. I also created a sample Outlook add-in to be displayed on the Appointment Surface adding the following in my manifest.xml -

```
<ExtensionPoint xsi:type="AppointmentOrganizerCommandSurface">
```

After enabling this add-in in my Outlook desktop application (Windows 10), it doesn't appear on the Appointment surface of my **O365 group calendar**. Although it appears on my primary calendar's appointment surface.
Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 0):

Currently the feature: addin in group calendar, you requested, is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our user-voice page. Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered, when we go through our planning process.

https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins